# How do I get string inside of xml attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, regex, xhtml

```
<z:row ows_Title='What does UFO stand for?'
 ows_Body='<div class="ExternalClassAA6E0BD0783B483F81A1B5E0C8DF15A5">
              <p>Unidentified Flying Object.​</p></div>' />
```

If i do `var width=$(this).attr("ows_MetaInfo");` where $(this) points to the z:row node I get the while markup. I only want to grab the value inside of paragrap tag "Unidentified Flying Objects"

Is regex an option?
Thank you for taking a look..

Comment: Parse the XML then parse the HTML as if it were in the DOM. Regex not needed and advised against.

Comment: You're asking how to fix a problem a specific way. That way is ill-advised. You might receive a better response by simply asking "how do I fix this problem, here's what I've tried..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no need in regex. You can simply try the following:

```
var p = $($(this).attr("ows_Body")).find("p").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either the `innerText` or `textContent` attribute of the div.

```
<div id="my-div">
    Flying UFOs
</div>

var d = document.getElementById('my-div');
alert(d.innerText);
```